# Type-safety for type unions without the need to force the use of a type guard?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have two similar objects which contain a discriminant `version` (ready for a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)). They differ in the second field (either `a` or `b`):

```
type Version1 = {
  version: 1;
  a: string;
};

type Version2 = {
  version: 2;
  b: string;
};

const version1: Version1 = { version: 1, a: "foo" };
const version2: Version2 = { version: 2, b: "bar" };
```

During runtime, it is decided which of the two versions is present (here simulated with randomness):

```
const oneOrTwo = Math.random() > 0.5 ? version1 : version2;
```

Of course, TypeScript can't know of which type `oneOrTwo` will be at compile time, so I want to use a type guard to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type:

```
const doSth = (obj: Version1 | Version2) => {
    // code doing stuff dependent on each version and returning these different versions   
    if (obj.version === 1) {
        // ✅ has type: Version1 inside of this function
        return version1;
    } else {
        return version2;
    }
}
```

When calling `doSth` with the random version `oneOrTwo` (`doSth(oneOrTwo)`), the TypeScript engine doesn't recognize which of the two versions gets returned. This makes sense, because TypeScript types are not present at runtime anymore.

```
// ❌ has type: Version1 | Version2
const versionOneOrTwo = doSth(oneOrTwo);
// ❌ type error and auto-completion only offers `version` field, not `a`
versionOneOrTwo.a;
```

So this is not a solution to my problem.

I want to offer the object `oneOrTwo` (which could either be `Version1` or `Version2` in e.g. a NPM package, so I can't expect the users to implement a type guard on their own like this:

```
const oneOrTwo = Math.random() > 0.5 ? version1 : version2;

if (oneOrTwo.version === 1) {
    // ✅ has type `Version1` --> auto-completion offers `a` field next to `version` field
    console.log(oneOrTwo.a);
} else {
    // ✅ has type `Version2` --> auto-completion offers `b` field next to `version` field
    console.log(oneOrTwo.b);
}
```

The only alternative I can think of is to offer the **intersection** of `Version1` and `Version2` as the type of `oneOrTwo` but this is quite unsafe.

Is there a way I don't have to force the user of the object `oneOrTwo` to implement a type-guard or use a type assertion? Or can I somehow make it obvious to the user that they have to use a type-guard?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAahBOBnAlgewHYEYoF4oG8AoKKANwRQwC4pMBuYqAQxsWHmXQHMGBfBwqEiwKadACZcBRuSRia4hiQBGrdpx6F+hQgGMMbMqIyYacOSan4jF9DUwAaZjQBEAM1SoXUbfvSHZSgkzYwkrGyCFJ1UoF2UmeG9tPQNgKAATVABlYAALKQAKVGUAKxDbbAAfEVtxAEpcAD5pEhJkNygi0oA6QLFcHDxMBqJWsagAegmoQFByKFymRCghaAADcyDMVahOFHToVA685CW3AFd0XWAxRnGoeAhgM-h0CLF6W58oCAAbRGhRnd7o9nq8+hhFJ9eFodH5DBgIAB5eAAFQA7qgpABZJh5brwJjoTIAWwKDWaAAZugBWKAAfjelho4IkAnQTGJEEQYCYumgAHVkHkAEqEkkbfqAkhTKAAQWW4GgXDOCXSO38yH2UEOzCg50u1wwGVQXPQAHI0hj4ABrbVnYB7A5HXLQfVXG6fGVzBZLFZQdahKo1ILibaLb4AD0gVwg6U+cLSLMR6CRqIxUkyOVyRRTyPRqDqSlaXoVwgQ8FQ8Ej0eAsc+SdzadQ3SYfDZHK5PL5UEFeQllilk2m8r9ytV6sd2o6TD1F3dRsypotUCtttQ9snOryrrnhvQOjGMsAMuTzcN+gMVKDVfsSVbx1JQRC5dc-dIAIQgN+weEzeQKLOGItpWmE8-XLStmCJZh7VQABafRiTAH5Hn6DAfhAKc3Aof0WW2NxkF+dInHQVA0lWJg7zGJ8X3fT9AxbNsdEIdlOW5XloBRRUAHEVXgNVBxlXt8hnUdeLVXZNWgbc9WQZDOhItIJK1HUZzdPcGiFFdK2tRAAEID1adpOgRPMMV6UIBiGEZPkPaZvTPRV-S-bZYNg5omBg+DUEQ5C90w7DyLwgjXygFMIzSYBMVWXCZMImzWjhVBkO6H5UC4HNU3zFtCyhb4-gBeLgNmU9fUci8QxctzoMiryfJQo1DiwpB-WUILCNCiBwuWKKYvwuKgSgRLktS9KTKbbplBysZoWhZiOzY7sAFV-ngAARCB8JTdJOMgHjxwE4coDOFbYP2TbY1LJUxONJc0hdH4wAMkgEx2RAv0KYoymDd4r2+iE6hoT7Xr+rAmhacYHieF4oBxPECSJbyySgSkaToIcoDNB5uQMCAzSgHkCU5WsqwUo7-nSfTpqAwaH1-fI8C6L73uvUJ6jBwcSEh0FXq-RmGgZACoGZVnqeSWyoBPH1LvKTZfpvcR738NJqLOV8P3en9sj-ACpuLEDLu+eAKyrMVqrghCkPq140IwxqAt64KiNC0j-Qoz4VbVuiKgYrQgA)

Interestingly, `doSth(version1)` has the same issue as `doSth(oneOrTwo)`. In this case, TypeScript somehow can't infer type `Version1` although it could be sure about it at compile time.

Comment: The playground link appears to be broken. But fundamentally `doSth` returns `Version1 | Version2`, because it could return either, depending on what it receives. If you want `doSth(version1)` to work, you'd have to provide [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

Comment: *"Is there a way I don't have to force the user of the object oneOrTwo to implement a type-guard or use a type assertion?"* You seem to be using the term "type guard" to mean any check of which branch of the union a value is. If there are genuinely two different kinds of values in your API which need to be handled differently, then how could this possibly be done safely without checking which kind of value something is in order to handle it the appropriate way? How could users not be expected to do that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've fixed the TS playground link and edited the question to better reflect its purpose. I want to provide an object `oneOrTwo` which could either be of one or another type (not a function). So function overloads won't help me. The function `doSth` is just an unsuccessful attempt to improve type safety.

Comment: For an analogy, consider if you have a method in your API which can return an object or `undefined`. Then Typescript will require users to check that the value is not `undefined` before they access any properties on the object - because users *genuinely do have to check that* - if `undefined` is a possible value then it needs to be handled. The same applies to any other union type; if you don't check which kind of value it is, then you can't expect to do anything that only works for one kind and not the other.

Comment: @kaya3 In my scenario I can do the check for the user. My issue originates from React Native where I can check via a function of the `react-native` package whether the user is using `iOS` or `Android`. I already do this conditional check inside of my package (with `react-native` as a dependency) and return values only relevant for `iOS` (`Version1` in my example) in one case and values only relevant for `Android` (`Version2` in my example) in the other. Given your analogy, in my scenario I genuinely know whether something indeed is `undefined`. Can't TypeScript handle such a scenario?

Comment: Logically if the user could be using either Android or iOS then you *don't* know which it is, and you do have to check. If your goal is to provide an API which is able to be used the same way by users targeting Android or iOS, then you shouldn't need to expose this union type to the consumer of the API at all; provide an interface of the common properties and methods, let the users use those properties and call those methods, and deal with the distinction within your own library (but where you deal with the distinction, you will need to distinguish them, either by a union or by polymorphism).

Comment: Alternatively, if you want consumers of the API targeting iOS to be able to use the API in a different way than those targeting Android, where the consumers targeting iOS know they should be getting the iOS versions of the data, then the API needs to provide consumers targeting iOS with some API call that returns values of the specific type they should know they are getting, rather than a union of that type and Android's type.

Comment: Maybe a bit off-topic. But also if it is only two versions maybe type predicates can help, something like: `const isVersion2 = (obj: Version1 | Version2): obj is Version2 => (obj.version === 2);` then when you check `if (isVersion2(oneOrTwo))` it will narrow type in `if` statement and `else` statement too.

Comment: I don't quite get the issue...  It looks like you and kaya3 have already discussed this but I'm trying again.  Backing up, let's imagine that there's only JavaScript.  How would you expect users to know whether they should be looking at `oneOrTwo.a` or `oneOrTwo.b`? The TypeScript typings can come after you make that decision.  In the question you say "I can't expect the users to implement a type guard on their own" and in the comments you say "In my scenario I can do the check for the user"... could you demonstrate this with a simple example that works at runtime?

Comment: One way to approach this (and again, not really different from kaya3's suggestion) is to wrap the thing in some common interface like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOJKrW) so that under the hood there are two different versions but the users only see a single version.  Does that make sense?  I can maybe write that up as an answer if it meets your needs, but I suspect I'm missing something or else you'd already have been on board with previous comments.

Comment: @kaya3 you and jcalz are right. I can't really know at compile time which version it's going to be. If there's only JavaScript I can't know beforehand. I think I had a misconception here because this issue arose during a conversion of JS code TS code.

Comment: I thought that TypeScript could provide me with some common interface, as you described verbally @jcalz. However, I don't understand the implementation of the common interface in the TS Playground file you linked. I have the feeling, that this might what I'm looking for, but especially the line `wrappedOneOrTwo.aOrB = "hello";` looks odd to me. Hence, a reply alongside that code would be very helpful! As an alternative, I'm thinking of offering two versions of the library, a standard one (intersection of both versions) and a more type-safe one (union) which forces the user to add a check.